# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException on worker node in spark standalone mode

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting the following error when trying to submit spark job using spark-submit. I am unable to understand the error what exactly it's asking for.

It is failing at below line.

```
spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").
          option("spark.mongodb.input.partitioner", "MongoSinglePartitioner").
          option("uri", connectionString).
          load()
```

Here is my spark submit command:

```
spark-submit \
 --class com.sparkTutorial.input \
 --deploy-mode cluster \
 --master "spark://master-node:7077" \
 --packages com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:7.4.1.jre11 \
 --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1 \
 target/scala-2.12/sql-mongo-validation-assembly-0.1.jar
```

Logs on a worker node.

```
Spark Executor Command: "/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark/conf/:/opt/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx2048M" "-Dspark.driver.port=36881" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10s" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@localhost:36881" "--executor-id" "36" "--hostname" "172.22.0.5" "--cores" "2" "--app-id" "app-20210907192950-0004" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@172.22.0.5:46711"
========================================

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
21/09/07 19:30:30 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 22087@bbc2066271a2
21/09/07 19:30:30 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for TERM
21/09/07 19:30:30 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for HUP
21/09/07 19:30:30 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for INT
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/opt/spark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.1.2.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
21/09/07 19:30:31 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
21/09/07 19:30:31 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
21/09/07 19:30:31 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
21/09/07 19:30:31 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
21/09/07 19:30:31 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
21/09/07 19:30:31 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1748)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$9(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:413)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcVI$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcVI$sp.java:23)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:877)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:158)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:876)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$7(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:36881
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:287)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:230)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:36881
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: _Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:36881_

Comment: @GaëlJ spark-submit in client mode is working while in cluster mode, the above error is being thrown.

Comment: Would this port be the MongoDB or something else? If so, where are your worker nodes compared to the MongoDB?

Comment: MongoDB port is different. When running in cluster mode, I did setup SPARK_LOCAL_ID = 127.0.0.1 in the environment variable in master-node. I am suspecting it has to do something.